# Sub passed a user control as an object crashes in compiled program, not in IDE

Tags: vb6, controls, activex, executable

I have a function that is passed a user control (defined within the project) as one of it's parameters. This works just fine when run through the IDE. However, it often shows unexpected (although varied) behaviour when the compiled version is run - the most commonly observed (and problematic) being a brief hang, followed by a crash to desktop (no error messages). (Always Windows 7).

Roughly speaking, the code looks something like this:

```
Public Sub DoStuffToControl(ByRef ThisUserControl As MyUserControl)

    Dim refreshState As Boolean
    Dim I As Long

    refreshState = ThisUserControl.Redraw
    ThisUserControl.Redraw = False
    for I = 0 to 1000
        'Do something to the control
    next I
    ThisUserControl.Refresh
    ThisUserCOntrol.Redraw = refreshState

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to be more specific than 'unexpected (although varied) behaviour'

Comment: Sorry, thought I'd formatted that better.